# Why do you have to include PHP file, when using namespace?

Tags: php, class, namespaces

Let's say i've declared a namespace like this:

```
<?php
// File kitchen.php
namespace Kitchen;
?>
```

Why do i still have to include that file in all other files where i want to use kitchen.php 
Doesn't PHP know that kitchen.php resides in Kitchen namespace?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Namespaces != autoload.

Comment: So namespace is like virtual directory and autoload is used to actually load files from directory? Can you use autoload with namespace? Thanks!!

Comment: Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php and here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php; reading the docs can go a long way :)

Comment: Great thanks! I am very new to all of this. Thanks for help! :)

Comment: thanks for asking @intelis, you have made all of us smarter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Namespaces make it extremely easy to create autoloaders for any class within your project as you can directly include the path to the class within the call.

An pseudo code namespace example.

```
<?php 
// Simple auto loader translate \rooms\classname() to ./rooms/classname.php
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
    require_once('./' . $class . '.php');
});

// An example class that will load a new room class
class rooms {
    function report()
    {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($this, true) . '</pre>';
    }

    function add_room($type)
    {
        $class = "\\rooms\\" . $type;
        $this->{$type}  = new $class();
    }
}

$rooms = new rooms();
//Add some rooms/classes
$rooms->add_room('bedroom');
$rooms->add_room('bathroom');
$rooms->add_room('kitchen');
```

Then within your ./rooms/ folder you have 3 files:
`bedroom.php`
`bathroom.php`
`kitchen.php`

```
<?php 
namespace rooms;

class kitchen {
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->type = 'Kitchen';
    }
    //Do something
}
?>
```

Then report classes what classes are loaded

```
<?php
$rooms->report();
/*
rooms Object
(
    [bedroom] => rooms\bedroom Object
        (
            [type] => Bedroom
        )

    [bathroom] => rooms\bathroom Object
        (
            [type] => Bathroom
        )

    [kitchen] => rooms\kitchen Object
        (
            [type] => Kitchen
        )

)
*/
?>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I guess he's asking why lazy loading isn't built-in by default.